# CSS style button For WP Login Function in page template

Tags: css, templates, wp-login-form, buttons

I am using Avada theme.

I have a page template created where I placed the WP Login function:

```
 <?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

Here is a live page: https://webariaserverfour.com/content-restricted/?r=246

Even though I have a global style for buttons in theme, the "Log in" button shows as default one.

I tried inspecting element and adding some styles to it, but the button remain the same.

If I could ask for an advice how to apply my theme style or even style manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can add styles to it in the inspector no problem. It's just a standard submit input element.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a function to style the login form:

```
function my_login_css() {

?>
 <style type="text/css">
 #wp-submit {
  border-color: #777;
  background: #999;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none; 
  border-radius: 0px;
 }
 #wp-submit:hover {background: #ccc}

</style>
 <?php
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_css');
```

When using a theme, like Avada, it's best to add these custom functions to a child theme. [More information, specific to Avada](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/special-features/avada-hooks-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: While this worked for my default WP login https://webariaserverfour.com/wp-login.php it did not affect the login form in my page template login https://webariaserverfour.com/content-restricted/?r=246. 
PS I am using a child theme.